# JQuery get checkbox id

Tags: jquery, checkbox, coffeescript

I'm trying to get an `id` of a checkbox.
There are several checkboxes on a page that have `id`s like: `channel_left_restream_ids_42`, `channel_left_restream_ids_44`, etc. I need to handle an event when one of those checked and get an `id` of the checked.

So for checkbox with code `<input type="checkbox" value="42" checked="checked" name="channel[left_restream_ids][]" id="channel_left_restream_ids_42">` and coffescript like this:

```
$("input[id*=channel_left_restream_ids]").change (e) =>
  alert($(this).attr("id"))
```

I can't get it work. It says `undefined`. I've tried a lot of alternatives, none worked. Where am I doing a mistake?

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/68co2mtm/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpectedly, the problem was not in jQuery or smth like this.
That was simply a problem of a bold array in my Coffee.
Replacing `$("input[id*=channel_left_restream_ids]").change (e) =>` with `$("input[id*=channel_left_restream_ids]").change (e) ->` (difference is only with an array at the end of the line) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In your jfiddle I gave each checkbox a class name of getId and used this code.

This should get you in the right direction.

```
$(".getId").each(function(){
  $(this).on("change", function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
     console.log(id);
  });
});
```

If the checkboxes all have the same name, you can use that too.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I am understanding your question right, but I hope this might push you in the right direction:

To know if that this specific checkbox is checked or not, you have to use its exact id.

So, in your script you are looking for this id:
      id*=channel_left_restream_ids

but the id of the checkbox is "channel_left_restream_ids_42"

I don't know the code you are working with, but it is possible that there are many "channel_left_restream_ids", or maybe that id is used on something else that is not a checkbox.

So this would be worth a try:
    [id*=channel_left_restream_ids_42]

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of checkboxes with different numbers after `restream_ids`. The thing is I need this event to be trigged on changing any of them. However, there's a JSFiddle link in my question, and if I add "_42" to selector nothing changes, you can see it. It still produces 'uindefined'